# how to embed firestore documents into a map in a field of another document?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have events collection, and I query 4 events that that will start soon. so I use this code to get that 4 events

```
const willStartSoonEventsSnapshot = await db.collection('events')
        .where("createdBy","==", event.createdBy)
        .where("isActive","==", true)
        .where("hasBeenApproved","==", true)
        .where("dateTimeStart",">",now)
        .limit(4)
        .orderBy("dateTimeStart","asc")
        .get()
```

and then, I want to embed that 4 events documents in a user document in a field called `upcomingEvents` which is a Map, the result should be like this

[image]

but I confuse how to embed that 4 event snapshots to be Map in a field of another document like that ?

```
await db.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({
    upcomingEvents : ..... //map here
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick. We use the [`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#for-each) method to loop over the results of the query and build a JavaScript object by using the [square brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```
  const willStartSoonEventsSnapshot = await db
    .collection('events')
    .where('createdBy', '==', event.createdBy)
    .where('isActive', '==', true)
    .where('hasBeenApproved', '==', true)
    .where('dateTimeStart', '>', now)
    .limit(4)
    .orderBy('dateTimeStart', 'asc')
    .get();

  let upcomingEvents = {};

  willStartSoonEventsSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    upcomingEvents[doc.id] = {
      city: doc.data().city,
      title: doc.data().title
    };
  });

  await db.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({
    upcomingEvents
  });
```